# Abnormal memory consumption of process "GeckoMain" when uploading chunks of very large files in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, file-upload, memory-leaks

I am trying to upload very large files (some are +30GB) by chunks. I was using Vue.JS and the dropzone library but noticed that when using Firefox (but not with Chrome) and uploading large files, the memory would blow up (the process "GeckoMain" seems to grow as big as the file itself). After writing my own chunk uploading code, the same problem appeared.

So I reproduced the chunk uploading part in a smaller setup with just a bit of html/javascript and a flask server in the backend. You can see by uploading a large file the memory consumption growing in Firefox whereas using Chrome it does not. Does someone have an idea of what is going on here ? Should I use something different than file.slice ?

While the process "GeckoMain" is growing in memory, if I use the developer tools and snapshot the memory, before, during and after the upload, it does not change.

The frontend code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>File Uploader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      id="file"
      type="file"
      name="static_file"
      onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"
    />
    <script>
      function onChunkLoad(oEvent, oreq, file) {
        let chunk_start = parseInt(sessionStorage.chunk_start)
        let chunk_size = parseInt(sessionStorage.chunk_size)
        let resp = JSON.parse(oreq.response)
        chunk_start += chunk_size
        sessionStorage.chunk_start = chunk_start
        if (chunk_start < file.size) {
          createChunk(file)
        } else {
          console.log('Upload ended')
        }
      }

      function uploadChunk(file, chunk_form) {
        let oreq = new XMLHttpRequest()
        let upload_chunk_url = '/upload_static_file'
        oreq.open('POST', upload_chunk_url, true)
        oreq.onload = event => onChunkLoad(event, oreq, file)
        oreq.send(chunk_form)
      }

      function createChunk(file) {
        let nb_chunks = parseInt(sessionStorage.nb_chunks)
        let chunk_start = parseInt(sessionStorage.chunk_start)
        let chunk_size = parseInt(sessionStorage.chunk_size)
        let chunk_counter = parseInt(sessionStorage.chunk_counter)

        chunk_counter += 1
        let chunk_end = Math.min(chunk_start + chunk_size, file.size)
        let chunk = file.slice(chunk_start, chunk_end)
        let chunk_form = new FormData()

        chunk_form.set('file', chunk, file.name)
        chunk_form.set('chunkbyteoffset', chunk_start)

        sessionStorage.chunk_counter = chunk_counter
        sessionStorage.chunk_end = chunk_end

        uploadChunk(file, chunk_form)
      }

      function handleFiles(files) {
        let file = files[0]
        let chunk_size = 256 * 1024 * 1024
        let nb_chunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunk_size)
        let chunk_start = 0
        let chunk_counter = -1

        sessionStorage.chunk_size = chunk_size
        sessionStorage.nb_chunks = nb_chunks
        sessionStorage.chunk_start = chunk_start
        sessionStorage.chunk_counter = chunk_counter


        createChunk(file)
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the backend code as well :

```
import io

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_message():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/upload_static_file", methods=["POST"])
def upload_static_file():
    file_form = request.form
    file = request.files.get("file")
    filepath = file.filename
    chunk_offset = int(file_form["chunkbyteoffset"])
    with io.open(filepath, "ab") as f:
        f.seek(chunk_offset)
        chunk = file.stream.read()
        f.write(chunk)

    resp = {"success": True, "response": "file saved!"}
    return jsonify(resp), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

UPDATE :
TL;DR : Memory leak might come from very fast repeated calls to "file.slice" in Firefox, ReadableStream solves the memory problem but you lose the ability to read the file "anywhere" quickly.

Following Keith advice to use a ReadableStream instead of file.slice, it is indeed possible to then upload chunks without the memory leak. This could suggest that fast repeated calls to file.slice in Firefox may cause some kind of memory leak. I couldn't find any issue or statements about that behavior.
ReadableStream solves the memory issue but then you lose the ability to retrieve any "slice" of the file you want without having to read through the beginning and discard it. Is there another way that could help me with that ? (For resumable uploads, I need to be able to read any slice of the file I want)

Comment: Rather than slice, you could maybe try the Readable Stream that's available on Blobs. -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this solves indeed the memory problem but it seems I cannot read the file 'anywhere I want' with the stream. I updated the original post. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This is the type of stuff Stack Overflow was originally created for. I do have a question for you. Do you know exactly what the GeckoMain process is? It seems to run on my Linux (ubuntu 21.10) machine, but not windows, even when I closed firefox. I am guessing it belongs to either GNU, Debian, or Ubuntu but I dont really know. Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, doing this bit as an answer, as it's a tad large for comment.

But from what I can gather using the ReadableStream solves the memory issue, but then we loose the seek option of slice.

Now there might be 2 options here depending on what FF is doing.

Option 1:  If FF is indeed reading the whole file first, we can check that by doing a single slice at the end of your 30gig file, if the memory usage goes up again, we know that's what FF is doing.  If so, a simple solution using the ReadableStream is just ignore the bytes read until we get back to the position you want to resume from, hopefully shouldn't be any slower if that's what FF is doing anyway.

> Ok, the below I wrote before I noticed FF does not have support for
> showOpenFilePicker,  So Option 1 looks like it might be the only
> option..  :(

Options 2: If the memory usage doesn't go up, then what we could maybe do is use the FileSystemAPI instead, with this we get a FileSystemFileHandle, this has a method called `getFile()`, and once you have this fileHandle you can request this multiple times without the user having to select the file again. So if after X number of blocks we just call getFile() again, this should then loose the reference to the previous FILE(Blob) and then get garbage collected. The changes shouldn't be too large either, instead of using INPUT type file, you get the fileHandle using `const handle = await window.showOpenFilePicker()`, and then for the FILE,  `const file = await handle[0].getFile()`, you can then do slice etc on the file object as before.

Comment: Yes I implemented Option 1 for now, it's just that reading through the file and ignoring the beginning for a 30GB file can take roughly one or two minutes so I was hoping to have another solution with direct access. As for file.slice, it's probably more complicated than what I stated, with a single call to file.slice to get the end of a big file, the memory of the process does not grow up. I'm absolutely not familiar with how javascript handles garbage collection but perhaps very fast repeated calls to file.slice can generate some kind of problem.

Comment: @PierreL.  That's interesting, so slice doesn't take X amount of ram when slicing from the end.. mmm..   I wonder if it's some tail recursion bug in FF.   Out of curiosity instead of  `createChunk(file)`, does `setTimeout(() => createChunk(file), 1)` make a difference?..

Comment: No it does not, with the timeout the process "GeckoMain" still consumes roughly the file size in memory

Comment: This is a dup comment from above, I want to que anyone I can to get a response, and will delete one of the comments in the next day or 2.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This is the type of stuff Stack Overflow was originally created for. I do have a question for you. Do you know exactly what the GeckoMain process is? It seems to run on my Linux (ubuntu 21.10) machine, but not windows, even when I closed firefox. I am guessing it belongs to either GNU, Debian, or Ubuntu but I dont really know. Any info is appreciated.

Comment: @JΛYÐΞV  I think it's just the Firefox process itself (Linux / Debian), on my machine however it does disappear when I close Firefox.  I'm assuming on windows they just call it firefox.exe.. There is a thread here on it not been called firefox -> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1742606 , and talk about it been fixed too.